# Haskell Typeclass Inspection

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming

I would like to use haskell to implement a game, and would like to use a system of type classes to implement the item system. It would work something like this:

```
data Wood = Wood Int

instance Item Wood where
  image a = "wood.png"
  displayName a = "Wood"

instance Flammable Wood where
  burn (Wood health) | health' <= 0 = Ash
                     | otherwise    = Wood health'
      where health' = health - 100
```

where the Item and Flammable classes are something like this:

```
class Item a where
  image :: a -> String
  displayName :: a -> String

class Flammable a where
  burn :: (Item b) => a -> b
```

To do this, I would need a way to detect whether a value is an instance of a type class.

The Data.Data module gives a similar functionality so that leads me to believe that this is possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing fits into the Haskell type model. That a value is an instance of a type class should be provable statically.

Comment: Values cannot be instances of type classes. Types are instances of type classes.

Comment: See [this FAQ entry](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FAQ#I.27m_making_an_RPG._Should_I_define_a_type_for_each_kind_of_monster.2C_and_a_type_class_for_them.3F).

Answer (score 8):

Type classes are probably the wrong way to go here. Consider using plain algebraic data types instead, for example:

```
data Item = Wood Int | Ash

image Wood = "wood.png"
image Ash = ...

displayName Wood = "Wood"
displayName Ash = "Ash"

burn :: Item -> Maybe Item
burn (Wood health) | health' <= 0 = Just Ash
                   | otherwise    = Just (Wood health')
  where health' = health - 100
burn _ = Nothing -- Not flammable
```

If this makes it too hard to add new items, you can instead encode the operations in the data type itself.

```
data Item = Item { image :: String, displayName :: String, burn :: Maybe Item }

ash :: Item
ash = Item { image = "...", displayName = "Ash", burn :: Nothing }

wood :: Int -> Item
wood health = Item { image = "wood.png", displayName = "Wood", burn = Just burned }
    where burned | health' <= 0 = ash
                 | otherwise    = wood health'
          health' = health - 100
```

However, this makes it harder to add new functions. The problem of doing both at the same time is known as the [expression problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem). There is a [nice lecture on Channel 9 by Dr. Ralf Lämmel](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Dr-Ralf-Laemmel-Advanced-Functional-Programming-The-Expression-Problem) where he explains this problem more in depth and discusses various non-solutions, well worth the watch if you have time.

There are approaches to solving it, but they are considerably more complex than the two designs I've illustrated, so I recommend using one of those if it fits your needs, and not worrying about the expression problem unless you have to.

Comment: The first one might work (though I don't think it would without a Data.Data hack), but it would make it more difficult to add more items (and there are over 200 of them).

The second would not work at all because some items aren't flammable. What I mean is that you might have `Wood` which is flammable and can be put into inventory and `Zombie` which is flammable and can fight.

These two items share a common trait, but also each have another trait which the other does not.

Comment: This is why I wanted to use type classes, the obstacle being that I would have to be able to test, for example, whether the item that the player is interacting with is flammable, which means testing whether is is a member of a typeclass.

Comment: @adrusi: Whether something is a member of a type class is a compile-time property, and thus it's not really suitable for what you're trying to do. From what you're describing, it sounds like the second approach should work, although you might need some modifications. That depends on what properties are in common between certain kinds of items. For example, if any item can have any combination of properties, you can just have a `Maybe` field for each property, like the one I have for flammable items. Items that don't have that property will just have a `Nothing` there.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the problem:

```
burn :: (Item b) => a -> b
```

What this means is that the result value of `burn` must be *polymorphic*. It must be able to fill *any* hole for *any* instance of `Item`.

Now, it's quite apparent you're trying to write something like this (in imaginary OO language with interfaces and subclassing):

```
Interface Item {
  String getImage();
  String getDisplayName();
}

Interface Flammable {
  Item burn();
}
```

In this sort of code, you're saying that `burn` will produce *some* item, without any guarantees about *what kind* of item it is. This is the difference between "for all" and "there exists". What you wanted to express in the Haskell code was "there exists", but what you actually expressed was "for all".

Now if you're *really* sure you want to do "there exists" functionality, you can take a look at using [Existential Types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type). But beware. If you are planning on writing code like this:

```
if (foo instanceof Flammable) {
  ...
}
```

Then you are almost certainly doing it wrong, and will run into much pain and agony. Instead consider hammar's suggested alternatives.